# Find the most hit url in a large file

Tags: algorithm, sorting, unix

I was reading [this Yelp interview on Glassdoor](http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/We-have-a-fairly-large-log-file-about-5GB-Each-line-of-the-log-file-contains-an-url-which-a-user-has-visited-on-our-site-QTN_254050.htm)

"We have a fairly large log file, about 5GB. Each line of   the log file contains an url which a user has visited on our site. We want to figure out what's the most popular 100 urls visited by our users. "

and one of the solution is

cat log | sort | uniq -c | sort -k2n | head 100

Can someone explain to me what is the purpose of the second sort (sort -k2n)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the stages are:

1) get the log file into the filter

2) get identical filenames together

3) count the number of occurrences of each different filename

4) Sort the pairs (filename, number of occurrences) by number of occurrences

5) Print out the 100 more common filenames

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does the first sort improves the efficiency of unique -c ?

Comment: @Fever: The first `sort` is required for `uniq` to work properly; it handles only adjacent identical lines.